# Scrape morningstar income statement using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.get(f"https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/{market_value}/{ticker_value}/financials")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(., 'Income Statement')]"))).click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Expand Detail View')]"))).click()
            data = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sal-columns sal-small-12']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
```

I have this code to scrape the table in morningstar, i can click the buttons but i cant scrape the div that contains the data.

Here is what the i did with the selenium:

1. It will open the website and go to the tab.
2. Inside the tab, a button with 'expand' will be clicked.
3. Once click, it will show a table.

Im trying to get the data inside the table

Comment: Can you please check that table is in frames or not? if it is not in frame then you have to use the dynamic xpath to get data from table.

Comment: It is not in frame, but the table is inside a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you want is contained in the div with the class `equity-financials-bottom`. Since it's not a table element, you'll have to do the parsing into a dataframe shape yourself.

At the same time, why not use the Export Data functionality? It gives you an .xls file that should be easier to parse.

Comment: data = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='equity-financials-bottom']"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
                

df  = pd.read_html(data)  


I tried this, but it doesnt give me anything when i print df.

Comment: FInally been able to get the data using export data. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wait using `time.sleep()` after you click on the button.

I tried before to use `WebDriverWait` but it didn't work.

Could you give me one of the URLs and I may help you

Comment: https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/financials

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can first find the size of tr and td tags

```
int trSize = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//table[@class='sal-summary-section__table']//tr").size();

int tdSize = driver.findelements(By.xpath("//table[@class='sal-summary-section__table']//tr/td").size();
```

Then you can iterate that using for....loop.

you need to generate a dynamic xpath for that.

```
    for (int i=1; i<= trSize  i++ ){
          for (int j=1; j<= tdSize  j++ ){
        
         String finalXpath="//table[@class='sal-summary-section__table']//tr["+ 
     i +"]/td["+ j +"]/span"
    
    String cellValue = driver.findelement(By.xpath(finalXpath).getText();
    
    system.Out.Println(cellValue);
  }

}
```